# How to display an asp.net mvc view as popup modal from an aspx page which will communicate with the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

I am loading an asp.net mvc view from a link in an aspx page using the following code. The problem is that the view is unable to communicate with the controller. Is there an alternate way to show a view in a modal popup which will communicate with the controller for retrieving and saving data from the displayed page?

```
      $(function () {
          $('body').on('click', '.draw-edit-Link', function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();

              $.get(this.href, function (html) {
                  $('<div />').kendoWindow({
                      visible: true,
                      title: 'My Documents',
                      modal: true,
                      width: '1200px',
                      deactivate: function () {
                          this.element.closest('.k-widget').remove();
                      }
                  }).data('kendoWindow')
                  .content(html)
                  .center()
                  .open();
              });
          })
      });

   <a id="drawEdit" class="draw-edit-Link" href="/MySite/Purchase/MyDocument>My Document</a>
```